# Regular Expression to extract parts of Twitter query

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following string from which I want to extract the `q` and `geocode` values.

```
 ?since_id=261042755432763393&q=salvia&geocode=39.862712%2C-75.33958%2C10mi
```

I've tried the following regular expression.

```
expr = re.compile('\[\=\](.*?)\[\&\]')
vals = expr.match(str)
```

However, vals is `None`. I'm also not sure how to find something before, say, `q=` versus `=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for a regex (using Python 3):

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> query = parse_qs(str[1:])
>>> query
{'q': ['salvia'], 'geocode': ['39.862712,-75.33958,10mi'], 'since_id': ['261042755432763393']}
>>> query['q']
['salvia']
>>> query['geocode']
['39.862712,-75.33958,10mi']
```

Obviously, `str` contains your input.

Since (according to your tag) you are using Python 2.7, I think you need to change the import statement to this, though:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
```

and if you were using Python before version 2.6, the import statement is

```
from cgi import parse_qs
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be easily done without regex:

```
string = '?since_id=261042755432763393&q=salvia&geocode=39.862712%2C-75.33958%2C10mi'
parts = string[1:].split('&') # the [1:] is to leave out the '?'
pairs = {}
for part in parts:
    try:
        key, value = part.split('=')
        pairs[key] = value
    except:
        pass
```

And `pairs` should contain all the key-value pairs of the string.

Comment: Whether it's regex or not, it's better to use existing, tested code like urllib.

Comment: Sure! I'm not so familiar with it.